# Nginx redirect from domain to subdomain

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

How to redirect form domain to subdomain?

```
server {
    server_name domain.pl www.domain.pl;
    return 307 sub.domain.pl;
}
```

creates redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try full domain url with redirect :)

```
server {
    server_name domain.pl www.domain.pl;
    return 307 http://sub.domain.pl;
}
```